# Technic Launcher always crashes when opening mod packs on OS-X

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos, minecraft-technic-pack

My Technic Launcher keeps crashing whenever I try to open mod packs, for example: Crafting Dead, or Hexxit.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Pops, is there any more info you can give us? any error message that pops up?

Comment: Certain mod packs are hardware-specific -  I know Hexxit is very RAM-consuming. Some packs might not even load - on my netbook, I can't play Tekkit at all.

Answer (score 0):

If it says bad graphics card: update graphics card somewhere in the error you need to update your graphics card.

Answer (score -2):

erase it
and redownload then it should work